# How do you use multiple values from UNNEST in WHERE clause of a subquery?

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Using Standard SQL on BigQuery, I am trying to select  only certain values from a column, dependant on what values are stored inside an array on the same record.

For example, each record contains the event_timestamp column, and an array of user properties. I would like to select only the event_timestamps for the events where a specific user property is met, e.g. key = 'Level_Number' and value.string_value = '04'; but I need to do this for multiple user properties in the same table, e.g. timestamps where value.string_value = '04' in one field and then where value.string_value ='05' in the next.

The problem is that when I try to do this I am getting the Error: "Scalar subquery produced more than one element".

For example, these are queries which I have tried:

```
SELECT
user_pseudo_id AS user_id,
(SELECT TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) from `analytics_161693185.events_*`
  WHERE EXISTS 
      (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST (user_properties) WHERE key = "Level_Number" AND value.string_value = '02'))  AS time_turned_02,   
FROM `analytics_161693185.events_*`
```

```
SELECT
user_pseudo_id AS user_id,
(SELECT TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) from `analytics_161693185.events_*`
  WHERE
      (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST (user_properties) WHERE key = "Level_Number") = '02')  AS time_turned_02,   
FROM `analytics_161693185.events_*`
```

```
SELECT
user_pseudo_id AS user_id,
(SELECT TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) from `analytics_161693185.events_*`
  WHERE
      (SELECT key FROM UNNEST (user_properties)) = 'Level_Number'
      AND (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST (user_properties)) = '02') AS time_turned_02,   
FROM `analytics_161693185.events_*`
```

But all of them give the same error.

I know that one solution is to create temporary tables using code similar to the following:

```
WITH
temporary_table_02 AS(
SELECT
user_pseudo_id AS user_id,
TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) AS time_turned_02,
FROM `analytics_161693185.events_*`
WHERE (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) WHERE key = "Level_Number") = '02' 
),
```

This then allows you to select the values from these tables and join them in a new table, but since there are 18 levels, creating 18 temporary tables results in BigQuery saying the query is too complex, so this solution is not feasible.

Here is a sample of the data if it helps make things clearer:
[Data Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQaUj.png)

Here is a spreadsheet showing how I would like the Expected Results to look, from a simplified schema. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QGsp5ko54ZtRIdYejoA3tcJ99PCml6dL7sMRJRdLQzc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You put some parenthesis wrong, and you don't need the FROM clause for the `unnest`

```
SELECT
user_pseudo_id AS user_id,
TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) 
from `analytics_161693185.events_*`
  WHERE EXISTS 
      (
       SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST (user_properties) 
       WHERE key = "Level_Number" AND value.string_value = '02'
      )
  AND EXISTS 
      (
       SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST (user_properties) 
       WHERE key = "another key" AND value.string_value = '03'
      )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the solution you posted puts the WHERE clause outside of the SELECT section, meaning that I would only be able to select the timestamps in that table, I wouldn't then be able to select the timestamps for value.string_value = '03' in the same table as well.

Comment: That will still select all timestamps that meet both conditions into one field though. I need timestamps where value.string_value = '02' to go into one column and timestamps where value.string_value = '03' to go into a different column.

Comment: Why would be different timestamp? In your schema you have only one timestamp for the row. Post a simple CSV table and expected results example, as something is not clear.

Comment: Yes there is only one timestamp for the row, but a user can have many rows with different values for Level_Number, I need the timestamps where the Level_Number is 03 to go into one column and the timestamps where the Level_Number is 02 to go into a different column. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QGsp5ko54ZtRIdYejoA3tcJ99PCml6dL7sMRJRdLQzc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can add scalar queries in SELECT statement as in here

```
SELECT
    user_pseudo_id AS user_id,
    TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp),
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) WHERE key = 'Level_Number' LIMIT 1) as LevelNumber
FROM `analytics_161693185.events_*`
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST (user_properties) WHERE key = "Level_Number")
```

Comment: That works well to pair timestamps up with the LevelNumbers by placing them side by side in columns, however, if I then wanted to select in a single table, different columns storing the timestamps for different LevelNumbers, I am still not sure how to do that. I.e. A column for user_id, then a column for the timestamp for that user_id where LevelNumber is 2, then a column for the timestamp for that user_id where LevelNumber is 3, etc.

Comment: Don't do that. Keep them as rows. Why do you need them as columns? Tell what you exactly need, then we can construct the final query.

Comment: At the end of the post I have added a spreadsheet showing how the expected results should look, I need them as columns as I will then be using the timestamps in a new query where I want to search for records between two timestamps, e.g. records where the timestamp is between the timestamp in column 02 and the column 03.

Comment: @AlfieBrae what I understand from the whole conversation and the expected output in the spreadsheets is that you need each user_id appearing twice, same column but different entries (rows). One for LevelNumber = 2 and one for LevelNumber = 3, which will have different event_timestamp but same user_id. I think you are creating a bit of a confusion when saying that you need them in different columns and that instead of that you are referring to different entries (rows). Could you please confirm this?

Comment: I would have a long table with columns user_id, level, timestamp. And then pivot it in Excel, Data Studio or Python. Whatever you prefer.
You can use user_id as index variable and level as pivot variable.